# When customizing your iWatch face the time changes to 10:09

Tags: wearables

I'm curious why Apple uses the 10:09 time as a default when changing your Apple Watch face. I've seen this even in their marketing content. Is it the best time to be displayed for marketing purposes? Because it's somewhat symmetrical? The date stays consistent to the day.

Answer (score 11):

### This is a solid style convention about clocks in advertising

It serves to both:

1. Show company logo (usually on the top of the watchface) clearly and
2. Create a psychological feeling that the clock is "smiling" (\ /) rather than sad (/ \) or on another meaningless position.

There's also [this very good article](http://www.nytimes.com/2008/11/28/business/media/28adco.html) on The New York times covering the issue

### It can also have a golden rectangle-related effect

[MONZINGO](http://www.fq.math.ca/Scanned/21-2/monzingo.pdf) further says that the aproximation with the Golden Rectangle also helps the visual appeal (altough he also says that the 8:18, or "sad face", is also close to the golden ratio).

Comment: Other interesting article: http://mentalfloss.com/article/22461/why-1010-default-setting-clocks-and-watches

Comment: 14:50 is also used for the same reasons

Comment: @AndrewMartin, interesting, but something made me feel unease about this arm position

Answer (score 1):

Through history, the advertising convention for time in clocks was 10:10. Nobody disputed that, in any case some watch makers used different positions for the seconds: **Rolex** has a preference for 10:10:31; **TAG Heuer** sets its wristwatches to 10:10:37; **Bell & Ross** displays time at 10:10:10. **Timex** is one example of someone deviating from the norm: they set the time at 10:09:36.

As for Apple, there's not an official release, more like speculations:

> By setting the Apple Watch to 10:09, Apple is able to pay homage to
>   the long lineage of mechanical watches that preceded it. It's also
>   Apple's way of declaring that the Apple Watch is, despite all of its
>   advanced digital components, a bonafide timepiece that deserves to be
>   mentioned in the same breath as more traditional watches. From Apple's
>   vantage point, the Apple Watch isn't a smartwatch. On the contrary,
>   it's a modern watch that just happens to be extremely smart. The
>   difference is subtle, yet distinctly important.
>
> Apple has never once referred to the Apple Watch as a smartwatch. For
>   a company as detail oriented as Apple, this is no coincidence. Apple
>   is effectively saying that the Apple Watch doesn't belong in the same
>   category as the Galaxy Gear (itself set to 12:45) or the lazily named
>   Sony Smartwatch 2. The Apple Watch, Apple is telling us, is an
>   elegantly designed device that is as much about fashion as it is about
>   advanced technology. The Apple Watch, Apple is telling us, is a modern
>   take on a traditional watch, not a geeky smartwatch meant for a niche
>   audience. Setting the time on the Apple Watch to 10:09 is arguably a
>   reflection of this mindset and underscores Apple's own understanding
>   of what the Apple Watch is and who the intended audience is --
>   everyone.
>   *From: [Why is time on Apple Watch promotional ads set to 10:09?](http://www.engadget.com/2014/11/18/why-is-time-on-apple-watch-promotional-ads-set-to-10-09/)*

---

> Apple has a history of choosing a display time that has some
>   significance, famously setting the time on all of its iPhone
>   promotional materials and images to 9:41, the approximate time of day
>   when Steve Jobs first unveiled the iPhone to the world back in 2007.
>
> So why 10:09 for the Apple Watch? Apple appears to be making a
>   statement about being ahead of the curve when it comes to
>   smartwatches, and the facts back this theory up.
>   *From: [Here's why the Apple Watch always shows the time as 10:09 in advertisements](http://www.businessinsider.com/why-apple-watches-all-display-1009-in-advertisments-2015-3)*

---

> I think this is more about symmetry, about attention to detail, than
>   about being ahead of the curve. At 10:10, the hour hand will be 1/6 of
>   the way between the 10 and the 11 on the watch face. If the minute
>   hand is precisely on the 2 (as it would be at 10:10), the minute and
>   hour hands would not be symmetrical. At 10:09, the hands would be much
>   closer to symmetrical perfection.
>   *From: [Why Apple Watch shows 10:09 in all its ads](http://www.loopinsight.com/2015/03/10/why-apple-watch-shows-1009-in-all-its-ads/)*

## However...

As you may see, it's all speculation, the only real fact is the classic 10:10 time, where 10:09 is really close, so one could also speculate this has some marketing reasons, but it could also be (and as a matter of fact, probably is) a slight difference that tested better than 10:10